# How to take difference of two columns multiple times without writing a loop in a data frame

Tags: r

My data looks like this

```
ID   A_w B_w C_w  A_b  B_b  C_b
 1    3   4   6   0.5  0.2  0.9
 2    6   5   7   1.4  3.2  7.6
 3   12   11  27  5.4  3.2  6.1
```

My want to add new columns like `A_c = A_w - A_b`(same for `B_c` and `C_c`). The most straightforward way is probably to write a loop, but I wonder whether it could be done using `apply` or `lapply`. As you can see, the variable names have patterns. Additionally, it is always the difference between `dataframe[, x]` and `dataframe[, x+3]`.

As a novice in R, I found R documentation is not very helpful. For example, if I didn't accidentally see `.SD` is used to represent the subset in `lapply`, I will never know about its existence because it is not mentioned in the R documentation or any other online tutorials. Actually, stack overflow is the only place I see people ask about `.SD`. Any suggestions to deal with situations like this will be appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An idea via base R, using `sapply` over the unique names (before `_`). Then use `Reduce` to subtract the columns matching the unique names, i.e

```
m1 <- sapply(unique(sub('_.*', '', names(df[-1]))), function(i)
                                               Reduce(`-`, df[grepl(i, names(df))]))

#tidy and bind with original df, 
cbind(df, setNames(data.frame(m1), paste0(colnames(m1), '_c')))
```

Or avoid `cbind` and do it directly as @lmo proposes,

```
baseNames <- unique(sub('_.*', '', names(df[-1])))
df[paste(baseNames, "c", sep="_")] <- sapply(baseNames, function(i)
                                                     Reduce(`-`, df[grepl(i, names(df))]))
```

**Vectorized Solution**

Since you mention that *Additionally, it is always the difference between dataframe[, x] and dataframe[, x+3]*, then a fully vectorized way would be (keeping `baseNames` from before),

```
m1 <- matrix(seq(ncol(df)-1)+1, ncol = 2)
df[paste(baseNames, "c", sep="_")] <- df[m1[,1]] - df[m1[,2]]
```

**All of the above give,**

> ```
>   ID A_w B_w C_w A_b B_b C_b A_c B_c  C_c
> 1  1   3   4   6 0.5 0.2 0.9 2.5 3.8  5.1
> 2  2   6   5   7 1.4 3.2 7.6 4.6 1.8 -0.6
> 3  3  12  11  27 5.4 3.2 6.1 6.6 7.8 20.9
> ```

Comment: Maybe in one step with a stater line `baseNames <- unique(sub('_.*', '', names(df[-1])))` and then `df[paste(baseNames, "c", sep="_")] <- sapply(baseNames, ...`

Comment: Nice suggestion ( as always) @lmo

Comment: @Sotos Thanks a lot! Need some time to study your codes, but it is exactly what I want to see.

Answer (score 0):

using `tidyr` and `dplyr` you can do this:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
df1 <- read.table(text="ID   A_w B_w C_w  A_b  B_b  C_b
1    3   4   6   0.5  0.2  0.9
2    6   5   7   1.4  3.2  7.6
3   12   11  27  5.4  3.2  6.1",header=T,stringsAsFactors=F)

df1 %>% gather(var,val,-ID) %>%
  separate(var,c("var1","var2")) %>%
  spread(var2,val) %>%
  mutate(c=w-b) %>%
  gather(var2,val,-ID,-var1) %>%
  unite(var,c("var1","var2")) %>%
  spread(var,val)

  ID A_b A_c A_w B_b B_c B_w C_b  C_c C_w
1  1 0.5 2.5   3 0.2 3.8   4 0.9  5.1   6
2  2 1.4 4.6   6 3.2 1.8   5 7.6 -0.6   7
3  3 5.4 6.6  12 3.2 7.8  11 6.1 20.9  27
```

Comment: Thanks! I expect to see something more concise, but your codes are also helpful to me to learn R.

Comment: Yes it's quite long compared to @Sotos's solution, but it's also less more general, it will work if you have a `A_z` column there for instance, or if you have more than 3 categories, or if you've already computed some `c` columns (though it will recompute them) etc...